# How to access raster NoData value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, raster

I am trying to programmatically access the NoData value in a raster dataset as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Two tools that come to mind to describe raster properties do not seem to be able to describe the NoData value: [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000000t000000) and [Get Raster Properties (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m7000000).

How can I programmatically access (i.e. `print`) the NoData value of a raster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

per comments - it seems the [raster band properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Raster_Band_properties/03q30000004r000000/) contain a read-only no data property.

```
import arcpy

desc=arcpy.Describe('rasterName')
print desc.noDataValue
```

resulted in a value of -3.40282346639e+38 on a single bad ESRI binary grid that i had lying around.

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution on an [ESRI blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/06/11/gathering-raster-properties-for-multiple-datasets-using-python/).  The idea is to convert the raster to a raster object and then access the specific NoData value with `.noDataValue`.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\temp'

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()

for raster in rasterList:
    rasterObj = arcpy.Raster(raster)
    noData = rasterObj.noDataValue

    print "NoData Value: %s \n" %noData
```

Comment: interesting. it might vary with the version of arc - but [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Raster_Band_properties/03q30000004r000000/) says that the no data value is a read only property - perhaps only for multi-band rasters?

Comment: Good call @fluidmotion--it appearas as if the documentation is different between 10.1 and 10.2.  I would be happy to accept your answer if you write it up and provide an example of the `.noDataValue` in action.  Thanks.